# URL path parameters in API Gateway not mapping to event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use a path parameter in API gateway "/forms/{form-id}".

I already set up the **method request** and **integration request**, but I still don't get the {form-id} in **event**. Here's the setup of method request and integration request.

Method request:
[screenshot](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/8/97e79e90e97a84859832338ecd794b39-full.png)

Integration request:
[screenshot](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/8/15ef6eae004122bce1edde4903a5b31f-full.png)

I know how I can do it with mapping templates or lambda proxy. But right now something supposed to work is in fact not and I want to troubleshoot instead of going for another direction.

Comment: have you found a solution?